# How to remove unused parameters in MYSQL and asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, parameters

I use MYSQL with an ASP.NET website. My SQLS scripts are central in a table. For an UPDATE I use the following SQL command:

**UPDATE user SET active=@active, short=@short, userimage=@userimage, adminunit=@adminunit, admincc=@admincc WHERE (id = @ID);**

On the website I get the SQL and replace the parameters with the controls on the website (textboxes, checkboxes, dropdownlists...). This works very well for all the controls because they always have values. But the USERIMAGE is an image and I get the information from a fileupload control. As long as I select a file it works fine.

This code reads the values from the controls and save them in a parameterlist:

```
                        Case "GET"
                            If TypeOf control Is TextBox Then myParameterList.Add(New cParameter("@" + sField, CType(control, TextBox).Text))
                            If TypeOf control Is CheckBox Then myParameterList.Add(New cParameter("@" + sField, CType(control, CheckBox).Checked))
                            If TypeOf control Is DropDownList Then myParameterList.Add(New cParameter("@" + sField, CType(control, DropDownList).SelectedValue))
                            If TypeOf control Is Image Then
                            End If
                            If TypeOf control Is FileUpload Then
                                If CType(control, FileUpload).HasFile Then
                                    Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(CType(control, FileUpload).PostedFile.FileName)
                                    Dim contentType As String = CType(control, FileUpload).PostedFile.ContentType
                                    Using fs As Stream = CType(control, FileUpload).PostedFile.InputStream
                                        Using br As New BinaryReader(fs)
                                            Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)
                                            myParameterList.Add(New cParameter("@" + sField.Replace("FileUploadControl".ToLower, ""), bytes))
                                        End Using
                                    End Using
                                End If
                            End If
```

and this code builds the SQL:

```
                With cmd
                    .Connection = Connection
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    For Each sParameter As cParameter In myParameterList
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue(sParameter.Name, sParameter.Value)
                    Next
                    .CommandText = sSQL
                End With
```

So normally the SQL looks like this:

**UPDATE user SET active=True, short=testname, userimage=System.Byte[], adminunit=True, admincc=False WHERE (id = 12);**

But if no image is selected the SQL looks like:

**UPDATE user SET active=True, short=testname, userimage=@userimage, adminunit=True, admincc=False WHERE (id = 12);**

In this case the old image is lost and the databasefield *userimage* is null. Any ideas how to **ELEGANT** ignore/remove the parameters that are not used?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed**: changed the SQL to: userimage = IF(@userimage IS NULL, userimage, @userimage) –